# Why VideoStream class not open a external video URL?

Tags: php

I'm using a class for [video stream](https://gist.github.com/ranacseruet/9826293):

```
<?php
/**
 * Description of VideoStream
 *
 * @author Rana
 * @link http://codesamplez.com/programming/php-html5-video-streaming-tutorial
 */
class VideoStream
{
    private $path = "";
    private $stream = "";
    private $buffer = 102400;
    private $start  = -1;
    private $end    = -1;
    private $size   = 0;
 
    function __construct($filePath) 
    {
        $this->path = $filePath;
    }
     
    /**
     * Open stream
     */
    private function open()
    {
        if (!($this->stream = fopen($this->path, 'rb'))) {
            die('Could not open stream for reading');
        }
         
    }
     
    /**
     * Set proper header to serve the video content
     */
    private function setHeader()
    {
        ob_get_clean();
        header("Content-Type: video/mp4");
        header("Cache-Control: max-age=2592000, public");
        header("Expires: ".gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time()+2592000) . ' GMT');
        header("Last-Modified: ".gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', @filemtime($this->path)) . ' GMT' );
        $this->start = 0;
        $this->size  = filesize($this->path);
        $this->end   = $this->size - 1;
        header("Accept-Ranges: 0-".$this->end);
         
        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) {
  
            $c_start = $this->start;
            $c_end = $this->end;
 
            list(, $range) = explode('=', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], 2);
            if (strpos($range, ',') !== false) {
                header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
                header("Content-Range: bytes $this->start-$this->end/$this->size");
                exit;
            }
            if ($range == '-') {
                $c_start = $this->size - substr($range, 1);
            }else{
                $range = explode('-', $range);
                $c_start = $range[0];
                 
                $c_end = (isset($range[1]) && is_numeric($range[1])) ? $range[1] : $c_end;
            }
            $c_end = ($c_end > $this->end) ? $this->end : $c_end;
            if ($c_start > $c_end || $c_start > $this->size - 1 || $c_end >= $this->size) {
                header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
                header("Content-Range: bytes $this->start-$this->end/$this->size");
                exit;
            }
            $this->start = $c_start;
            $this->end = $c_end;
            $length = $this->end - $this->start + 1;
            fseek($this->stream, $this->start);
            header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
            header("Content-Length: ".$length);
            header("Content-Range: bytes $this->start-$this->end/".$this->size);
        }
        else
        {
            header("Content-Length: ".$this->size);
        }  
         
    }
    
    /**
     * close curretly opened stream
     */
    private function end()
    {
        fclose($this->stream);
        exit;
    }
     
    /**
     * perform the streaming of calculated range
     */
    private function stream()
    {
        $i = $this->start;
        set_time_limit(0);
        while(!feof($this->stream) && $i <= $this->end) {
            $bytesToRead = $this->buffer;
            if(($i+$bytesToRead) > $this->end) {
                $bytesToRead = $this->end - $i + 1;
            }
            $data = fread($this->stream, $bytesToRead);
            echo $data;
            flush();
            $i += $bytesToRead;
        }
    }
     
    /**
     * Start streaming video content
     */
    function start()
    {
        $this->open();
        $this->setHeader();
        $this->stream();
        $this->end();
    }
}
```

I can call this class by doing:

```
include_once 'videostream.php';
$stream = new VideoStream("video.mp4");
$stream->start();
```

This code works with local videos, but the problem is: When I try to open a external video like this:

```
$stream = new VideoStream("https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg");
```

The vídeo don't open and I don't receive any error messages? Is a fopen() problem? Is a server problem? I'm using xampp v3.3.0.

When I see Network tab in Google Chrome, I receive two headers and one of them is pending.

Comment: [allow_url_fopen may be disabled](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen)

Comment: @aynber my allow_url_fopen on php.ini is 'On'...

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE 1 (Partial Solution)**

After performing some tests I made some modifications to the code and I was able to open the video using an external URL, follow the corrections below:

1.*The video that I wanna play has HTTPS `(https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg)` and not HTTP format, so you must change all
headers that was HTTP/1.1 to HTTPS/1.1:*

```
header('HTTPS/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
header('HTTPS/1.1 206 Partial Content');
```

2.*The command `filesize` does not work when it comes to an external URL, so we need to create a function capable of getting the size of the file we want:*

```
function getContentLengthFromURL($url){
        $arrayHeaders = get_headers($url,true);
        if(isset($arrayHeaders['Content-Length'])){
            if(is_numeric($arrayHeaders['Content-Length']) && $arrayHeaders['Content-Length'] > 0){
                return $arrayHeaders['Content-Length'];
            }  
        }
        return null;
    }
```

*After that we need to update `setHeader()` function:*

```
//$this->size  = filesize($this->path);
$this->size = $this->getContentLengthFromURL($this->path);
```

3.*We need to comment out all the lines that specify the Content-Range: and Fseek()*

```
//header("Content-Range: bytes $this->start-$this->end/$this->size");
//fseek($this->stream, $this->start);
```

Amazing, now the HTML5 player is able to play the video, the **only problem** is that you are still unable to change the time of the video.

In this case I can't jump forward or back my video.

**UPDATE 2 (THE SOLUTION)**

After several attempts I finally got a solution to the code problem.

The problem was in the [content-ranges and in the positioning of the headers](https://github.com/micilini/video-stream/blob/master/src/Providers/VideoStreamProvider.php).

By the way, I created a videoStream package using the new code, if you want an automated videoStream, just access [this link](https://github.com/micilini/video-stream).